# Невозможно записать или создать файл - С# .NET Core + UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

Всем доброго времени суток!
Есть проблема, мне выбивает такую ошибку:

> Access to the path is denied.

Вот код записи:

```
public async void WriteQuestion()
{
            question = "Q: " + question + "\r\n";
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(nameTest))
            {
                await writer.WriteAsync(question);
            }

}
```

Что необходимо сделать, чтобы побороть это?
У меня проект хранился на облаке, думал из-за этого, но скопировал на локальный диск и вообще ничего не изменилось.

Comment: А какой путь в `nameTest`?

Comment: значение `nameTest` - в студию

Comment: Чего-то я сомневаюсь в возможности работы классов из `System.IO` в UWP, там же создано свое особенное подпространство [Windows.Storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Значение nameTest = string
Путь особо не важен, смена пути не помогло
По поводу работы классов...Насколько я знаю, UWP использует .NET Core, поэтому я сначала написал в консольном приложение логику кода, а потом перенес уже в интерфейс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение моей проблемы:

```
// получаем локальную папку
            StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            // создаем файл hello.txt
            StorageFile helloFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("hello.txt", 
                                                CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            // если файл уже ранее был создан, то мы можем получить его через GetFileAsync()
            // helloFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("hello.txt");

            // запись в файл
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(helloFile, text);
```